# How can you get a list of committers for each branch that is at least x commits behind master?

Tags: git

There are a few remote repositories that has a lot of branches. On the web UI side, a lot of them are 20+ commits behind. These branches are most likely abandoned by their committers, and I want to notify these committers to remove these branches.

I've seen snippets for getting the commits on one branch or another, but I'm interested in a list of branches and the latest committer of that branch given the branch is 20 commits behind master (regardless of how many commits they have ahead).

Are there git commands I can chain together to get this information?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a little bash script that tells you the branch "age" (time since last commit to that branch), and the committer responsible:

```
#!/bin/env bash
remote=${1:-/refs/heads}

for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)') ; do
    if [[ ${branch} =~ ${remote}/(.*) ]] ; then
        short_branch_name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        latest_commit=$(git log -1 --format="%at [%ar] %cn" ${branch})
        echo ${latest_commit} ${short_branch_name}
    fi
done | sort | cut -c 12-
```

Call it with `refs/remotes` to see all the branches without caring what you actually have checked out locally.  Here is some sample output on the `git` repo itself.

```
$ ~/Desktop/branch-ages.bash refs/remotes
[7 days ago] Junio C Hamano origin/maint
[25 hours ago] Junio C Hamano origin/HEAD
[25 hours ago] Junio C Hamano origin/master
[23 hours ago] Junio C Hamano origin/next
[23 hours ago] Junio C Hamano origin/pu
[22 hours ago] Junio C Hamano origin/todo
```

Add and delete format arguments to taste.

Comment: Although this doesn't exactly answer my question, it does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Wolf's solution is based on date, not # of commits. If you really want # of commits, what about a recipe that finds branches not yet merged into your branch, and for each of those branches listed, find the merge base and then count the number of commits from master back to that merge base and check that value for >= 20, and if so, extract the author's name/email from that branch's last commit.

```
  for branch in $(git branch --no-merge); do
    mergeBase=$(git merge-base $branch HEAD)
    numCommitsBack=$(git rev-list --count HEAD ^$mergeBase)
    if [ $numCommitsBack -ge 20 ]; then
       lastBranchAuthorEmail=$(git log -1 --format="%ae" $branch)
       lastBranchAuthorName=$(git log -1 --format="%an" $branch)
       echo $lastBranchAuthorName, $lastBranchAuthorEmail, branch $branch is $numCommitsBack commits behind HEAD
    fi 
   done
```

Comment: There's a shorter way to count commits (although beware of non-linear history, which affects both `git log` and `git rev-list` in the same way, which makes sense since `git log` *uses* `git rev-list` [well, they share source code]).  If `$basesha` holds the merge base and `$tip` is the SHA-1 of the branch tip, or is the branch name which therefore means the tip commit SHA-1, then `git rev-list --count $basesha..$tip` will get you the count (and `$basesha..$tip` is short for `$tip ^$basesha` which, in this case, functions the same as `$tip --not $basesha`).

Comment: Thanks torek, that is indeed a more direct way to count the commits.